# Can You Use Arithmetic Operators to Flip Between 0 and 1

Tags: algorithm

Is there a way without using logic and bitwise operators, just arithmetic operators, to flip between integers with the value 0 and 1?

ie.
`variable ?= variable` will make the variable 1 if it 0 or 0 if it is 1.

Comment: Note that in JavaScript, many of the answers below evaluate to a boolean, not a number. For example: `!x`, `(x <= 0)`, `(x == 0)`, etc.

Comment: Since the OP's need is often named "toggle" and described as "alternating", I'm mentioning these terms here. Ideally the mention will help people find this thread. These terms--and others that people think of--may be worth adding elsewhere in the thread to help search engines index the information.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

```
x = 1 - x
```

Will switch between 0 and 1.

Comment: To apply this more broadly, if `x` is in a specific range of positive numbers, then you can also use this to reverse its value (ie. `7-x` = 0/7, 1/6, 2/5, 3/4).

Answer (score 33):

*Edit:* I misread the question, thought the OP could use `any` operator

A Few more...(ignore these)

```c
x ^= 1       // bitwise operator
x = !x       // logical operator
x = (x <= 0) // kinda the same as x != 1
```

Without using an operator?

```c
int arr[] = {1,0}
x = arr[x]
```

Comment: ^ is a bitwise operator and ! is a logical operator.

Comment: While your second idea works, x = 1 - x is a much better solution. Having an array is overkill/wasteful.

Comment: `x = !x` is a good solution because it copes with values that aren't zero or one.

Answer (score 24):

Yet another way:

```
x = (x + 1) % 2
```

Comment: +1 because this will always give you 0 or 1 even if you accidentally give an integer outside that range.

Comment: @NickForge Cosidering that input other that 1 or 0 is illegal in scope of this question, are you sure that it is good that it won't protest on it?

Comment: @Alex whether or not that's a good thing depends on the language and expectations of "defensiveness". In C for example, booleans are stored as integers with more than 1 bit, so the concept of "illegal" is somewhat fuzzy.

Comment: Bingo! I wanted to perform an integer-based "XOR", and this does exactly that:  `x = (A + B) % 2` if A and B are both 0 or 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that it is initialized as a 0 or 1:

```
x = 1 - x
```

Answer (score 8):

Comedy variation on st0le's second method

```
x = "\1"[x]
```

Comment: And if you like that, you'll love `x = x["\1"];` (C and C++).

Answer (score 6):

Another way to flip a bit.

```
x = ABS(x - 1) // the absolute of (x - 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int flip(int i){
    return 1 - i;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for a bit of variety:

```
x = 1 / (x + 1);

x = (x == 0);

x = (x != 1);
```

Not sure whether you consider `==` and `!=` to be arithmetic operators. Probably not, and obviously although they work in C, more strongly typed languages wouldn't convert the result to integer.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply try this

```
+(!0) // output:1

+(!1) // output:0
```

Comment: This is highly language dependent though.

Answer (score -3):

You can use  simple:
`abs(x-1)`
or just: 
`int(not x)`